# How do I know what to take Challah from?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Tosefos in Pesachim 37b writes:

> חיוב חלה הוי משעת גלגול
>
> The obligation of Challah comes at the point of reincarnation

If I don't know who I am a reincarnation of, how do I know which dough I became obligated to take Challah from?  Is there any way for me to resolve this issue?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The מהרש״ע explains [תוספות](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=716) as follows:

> **תד״ה דכו״ע כו׳.** אבל בלילתו עבה כ״ע מודו דחייב בחלה אפי׳ על ידי משקה דהא חיוב חלה הוי משעת גלגול כו׳. נראה לפרש דגלגול דהא היינו שחזר אדם בגלגול לחטין וזקוק לכפרה ועילוי נשמה ומשו״ה קורין לו בלילתו עבה דהיינו דבתוך לילה שלו דהיינו בחשך של קבר הוא עבה מלשון עבריין. ואע״ג דאין מפרישין חלה מעיסה שנילושה במשקה בהא חייב כדי לזכות לו והיינו דמסיק דהא חיוב חלה הוי משעת גלגול.‏

Read it inside for full benefit, but, briefly: It's the wheat that is the reincarnation. Someone who deserves to come back as wheat needs merits, specifically the merit of the מצוה of חלה; thus, according to תוספות, even though one doesn't normally take חלה from dough made with sundry liquids, one does in this case.

Comment: Who is the maharsha with an ayin?

Comment: @Yitzchak, the _Maharasha_, not _Maharsha_. It's מורנו הרב רשע, abbreviated to מהרש״ע.

Comment: Oh, I remember him. I have his Chiddushei Aggados on revelation.

Comment: @Yitzchak He also has a well known commentary (only fragments remain) on the Haggadah.